# Best way to get rid of sargasso weed on beaches?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is my original image:
[image]

#### My goal is to get rid of the Sargasso seaweed on the beach.

I tried to clone but there wasn't enough surface area for me to clone. I tried using a paint brush but it doesn't look very natural:

[image]

Any recommendations on what I can do to remove them effectively?

Comment: Clone, brush, heal, content aware.. practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of patience;)

It gets a bit easier if you select & duplicate the area you're trying to clean, which stops you picking up bits of cliff in the healing, then it's just a case of chipping away at the seaweed with spot heal from the 'clean', seaward edges until you reach the cliff.

Lasso, save selection, copy, paste; restore selection, chip away…
This took a whole 30s, I'm sure with a bit more care it could be a lot better.

[image]

[image]